# CountDownTimer in a separate Class with message to the Handler on The calling fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know this isnt really needed but I want to practice the Handler and Message concept . I wrote a class extending CountDownTimer. in onTick, i sent Message to the Queue , and I know it's the UI queue, because the Class was instatiated on the Fragment.
In the Fragment I declared a Handler and overrided the handleMessage, trying to update a TextView with the timer pass in the Message.
In both classed - the UI fragment and the CountDown, the hander gets the getMainLooper, though I think both of them are already on the UI thread.
Though I see the messages being sent, I the Text View on the fragment isnt updating.
Please help me see what I am missing here .

```
public class GuitarExerciseTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            final String guitarExerciseTimerS = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Time Remaining %02d min: %02d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);


            Message completeMessage = Message.obtain();
            completeMessage.obj = guitarExerciseTimerS;
           // completeMessage.setTarget(mHandler);
            Log.d("TEST","prepare message" + " " + guitarExerciseTimerS);
            //completeMessage.sendToTarget()
            mHandler.sendMessage(completeMessage);

            ;
        }

    public class GuitarFocusedExerciseFragment extends Fragment{

        GuitarExerciseTimer timer = new GuitarExerciseTimer (30000, 1000);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.d ("TEST","Inside handelMessage");
                String timer = (String) msg.obj;
                guitarExerciseTimer.setText(timer);
            }
        };

        TextView guitarExerciseTimer;

}
```

Comment: Which is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope, I put a Log inside the HandelMessage but it never shows... its like they arent on the same thread or loop, though I know they suppose to be and both handlers (fragment and countdown classes) get the mainLooper. @Juan

Comment: So the problem is that the message doesn't show?

Comment: The text view on the Fragment doesnt Update, though the timer does work... the Log inside the Message does show the timer.

Comment: See if guitarExerciseTimer.invalidate() after setting the text does the trick.

Comment: Nope. I think I am not on the same thread or queue, though I dont understand why. The Log d insing the handleMessage() doesnt show on the monitor display.

Comment: Log timer to see that you actually are receiving what you expect.

Comment: Yep did it. there is a Log before message sent ... message initialized perfect with time.

Comment: I ment on the on receiving side, after String timer = (String) msg.obj;

Comment: Check that you are actually using two different handlers. One at the top and another one in the Fragment. The instance should be the same one in both cases.

Comment: You mean I need to pass the instance of Handler from the fragment to the CountDown class??? I thought because both are on the same thread, the the CountDown class was created from the fragment, then they should be on the same thread, queue and looper. the Log insided the handleMessage doesnt display at all, meaning it aint receiving anything.

Comment: The code to update the textview is in the handleMessage method you override for the specific Handler instantiation in the Fragment, so that code lives there only. The Handler you instantiated at the top is the base class which doesn't have the handleMessage overriden. So yes the countdown has to send the message using the Fragment's instance of handler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, solved but I still cant figure it out.
I did add the Handler to the constructor of CountDownTimer class
so I reference the Handler from the Fragment class.
It works now.
Still I thought that because those two classes live on the same Thread,
the handler should be common to both without This .
Guess I missunderstood the concept.
thank @Juan

Comment: Don't forget that the main use for Handlers is to use them from different threads. What you did now can easily be done with callbacks using observer pattern.